# Inserting magic number into class files

Tags: java, .class-file, magic-numbers

I have a jar in which all of the class files have their magic number and type removed, I am not very knowledgeable about this specific area.  What would be the best way to go about adding back in 0XCAFEBABE and the type back into each classfile and repacking the jar?

EDIT: i have checked, only the magic number is missing, the files are intact if i add it manually.

Comment: Why not simply look at the java source code? (I have a feeling I know the answer to this)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I think the OP is asking about this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#Magic_Number, which is nothing to do with source code.

Comment: How was the magic number removed? That seems like a very strange thing to have happen, and I wonder whether there is no further damage.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: ah, got it, thanks. I didn't know about this, and that's what I love about this site!

Comment: Would you like a java application to add this to the files again, or run something via a command line. What OS are you running?

Comment: Without knowing how or why the magic numbers were removed, its impossible to say what else was removed. e.g. if your files were converted as text at some point, you have little chance of recovering your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to do this at runtime, you could create your own classloader. I have attached some pseudo-code that might get you on the way:

```
public class MyClassLoader extends SecureClassLoader {

  @Override
  protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
     ...
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(brokenClassFile);
     BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
     ByteArrayOutputStream bas = new ByteArrayOutputStream((int) encryptedClassFile.length());
     byte[] wrongBytes = bas.toByteArray(); 
     byte[] goodbytes = ...     
     // add  a new byte[] and put in the appropiate missing bytes for the cafebabe and magic number
     CodeSource cs = new CodeSource(jarfile.toURI().toURL(), (CodeSigner[]) null);
     return super.defineClass(name, goodbytes, 0, bytes.length, cs);



  }

}
```

But i guess it is better to just fix the jar file using some OS tooling.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add the magic number back to the class files, you could use a simple shell script for this (assuming you are on Linux, or have Cygwin on Windows).

First create a file with just the 4 bytes of the header (CAFEBABE).

Then, extract the class files from the jar to some directory, and run this command at the root:

```
find . -name "*.class" | while read file; do
    mv ${file} ${file}-old
    cat /path/to/file/with/header ${file}-old > $file
    rm ${file}-old
done
```

Note: The above script works in bash, but you should be able to write something similar for any shell, or even for Windows.

But what do you mean by "have their magic number and **type removed**"? If the bytecode has been mangled in any way, the changes might be much more difficult to fix if not impossible.